# SpriteKit - Logging the debug info such as fps, NodeCount

Tags: objective-c, debugging, sprite-kit

I know how to display those info in the screen, but I would like to log them in a file/console for offline investigation. How could I do that?

Comment: You can't because you don't have access to the information printed to the screen. Plus what good would it do to have a long list of fps numbers? For performance analysis use Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure it yourself using scene `- (void)update` method. This method calls each frame need to calculate.

```
- (void)update
{
  self.frameCount++; // increase frame count value
  uint64_t currentTime = mach_absolute_time(); // get current time
  // according to this two values and last update method call time you're already can calculate the fps
  self.lastUpdateTick = currentTime; // remember for the future method call
}
```

To get the nodes count value you should just to count children of all the scene children. It may be some kind of recursive algorithm (not tested).

```
- (NSUInteger)childrenOf:(SKNode *)node
{
  NSUInteger count = 0;
  for (SKNode *child in node.children)
    count += [self childrenOf:child] + 1;
  return count;
}

- (void)calculateSceneChildrenCount
{
  NSUInteger count = [self childrenOf:self];
  NSLog(@"count is %lu",count);
}
```